# Getting 404 error with Spring Boot + REST application

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

basically I've been working in this multi module app using spring, but when I try to consume the services from my Rest controllers I keep getting this 404 error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-03T18:54:23.230+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/opus/auth/client"
}
```

Here is my app properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-self-references=false
server.servlet.context-path=/api/opus
```

Here is an example of one of the rest controllers:

```
package com.opus.restApi.implementations;

@RequestMapping("/auth/client")
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ClientRestController implements IClientRestController{

 @Autowired
    private IClientService service;

 @GetMapping("")
    public Iterable<Client> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

}
```

Here is my main class:

```
package com.opus.restApi;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.opus.app")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I can also share the master pom I'm using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.opus</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OpusApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>logic</module>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>restApi</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Here I can show you the pom I'm using for the rest module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.opus</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <artifactId>restApi</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <name>restApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opus</groupId>
            <artifactId>logic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.48</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/sockjs-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/stomp-websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: "*`@ComponentScan("com.opus.app")`*" - The `@RestController` is not "under" this package (it is in `com.opus.restApi.implementations`). Could you try setting `@ComponentScan("com.opus")` instead?

Answer (score 4):

Remove `@ComponentScan` from your main `RestApiApplication` class. `@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

```java
package com.opus.restApi;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RestApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This should fix the issue that seems to be related to your `ClientRestController` class not being scanned and thus no corresponding Spring-managed bean is created.

Comment: @Brik000, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer should definitely be accepted. Had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a list of all of your active endpoints by using one of these [methods](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-get-all-endpoints).

This will enable you to see the full list of endpoints your app exposes. Then, you either see the target endpoints in the list or you don't. If you do see them, this means you were previously using a wrong URI.

If not, it means the controller beans have not been added to the application context ... this is probably due to the `@ComponentScan` annotation pointing at the wrong package ...